# Does my scheduled task using "at" command run if I am logged out?

Tags: scheduling, at

I knew cron still runs, but how about `at`? Checked with `man at`, but it didn't mention it.

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that `atd` or an equivalent daemon is running, yes.